# Jenkins wget artifact using wildcard

Tags: jenkins, wget

I am trying to download jar artifacts using wget passing -A argument and wildcard "*.jar", however jenkins doesnt download the jar file. The same command works with a non-jenkins url. Has anyone got this working with jenkins. Highly appreciate your inputs.

```
wget --no-check-certificate --auth-no-challenge -A "*.jar" -r -l 1 -nd "https://jenkins.xxxx.com/job/xxxx/6/artifact/target/"
--2015-11-02 06:24:36--  https://jenkins.xxxx.com/job/xxxx/6/artifact/target/
Resolving jenkins.xxxx.com... 1.1.1.1
Connecting to jenkins.xxxx.com|1.1.1.1|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://jenkins.xxxx.com/job/xxxx/6/artifact/target/ [following]
--2015-11-02 06:24:37--  https://jenkins.xxxx.com/job/xxxx/6/artifact/target/
Reusing existing connection to jenkins.xxxx.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `index.html'
[ <=>                                                                                                                                                ] 12,420      --.-K/s   in 0s
2015-11-02 06:24:37 (592 MB/s) - `index.html' saved [12420]

Loading robots.txt; please ignore errors.
--2015-11-02 06:24:37--  https://jenkins.xxxx.com/robots.txt
Connecting to jenkins.xxxx.com|1.1.1.1|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2015-11-02 06:24:37 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Removing index.html since it should be rejected.

FINISHED --2015-11-02 06:24:37--
Downloaded: 1 files, 12K in 0s (592 MB/s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Revisiting this, I realize the Jenkins server *is actually unable to serve [its `robots.txt` file](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/war/src/main/webapp/robots.txt)*:

```
Loading robots.txt; please ignore errors.
--2015-11-02 06:24:37--  https://jenkins.xxxx.com/robots.txt
Connecting to jenkins.xxxx.com|1.1.1.1|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2015-11-02 06:24:37 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Following this 404 error, `wget` explains it will not keep the `index.html` it has downloaded:

```
Removing index.html since it should be rejected.
```

A quick lookup in the [`wget` manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Types-of-Files) yields on rejecting:

> (...) the accept/reject lists are matched **twice** against downloaded files:
>   once against the URL’s filename portion, to determine if the file
>   should be downloaded in the first place; then, after it has been
>   accepted and successfully downloaded, the local file’s name is also
>   checked against the accept/reject lists to see if it should be
>   removed. **The rationale was that, since ‘.htm’ and ‘.html’ files are
>   always downloaded regardless of accept/reject rules, they should be
>   removed after being downloaded and scanned for links, if they did
>   match the accept/reject lists**.

This means the URL you originally requested was downloaded and scanned for links, but none of the links matched `*.jar`, so none were retrieved. Then, the originally requested `index.html` was deleted because its name doesn't match `*.jar` either.

Looks like there are in fact no links to the `.jar` artifacts you want to download directly on this page. Ironically, this means I end up suggesting the same as before - try increasing subdirectory recursion by one level with `-l2` instead of `-l1`. As I stated in my previous answer, *I did try this on a local Jenkins install, and I actually needed `-l2` to download an artifact from there* (but the exact level may depend on the project setup and folder structure). Please try:

```
wget --no-check-certificate --auth-no-challenge -A "*.jar" -r -l2 -nd "https://jenkins.xxxx.com/job/xxxx/6/artifact/target/"
```